# Proof that $\frac {1} {2\pi i} \oint \frac {{\rm d}z} {P(z)} $ over a closed curve is zero.

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, analysis, contour-integration, cauchy-integral-formula

> Prove that $$\frac {1} {2\pi i} \oint \frac {{\rm d}z} {P(z)} $$ over a closed  smooth simple curve that contains all of the roots of the polynomial $P(z)$ is either zero if $n \geq 2$ or equals $\frac{1} {a_0} $ if it's degree is $1$.

Proof: $n\geq 2$ $$\frac {1} {P(z)=(z-z_0)(z-z_1)\dots(z-z_n)}$$ So after partial decomposition of the fraction I'll have something like $$\frac {A} {z-z_0} +\frac{B} {z-z_1}+\cdots$$ where $A,B \in \mathbb{C}$ (Is this fact true that $A,B$ wont be polynomials and just coefficients I can see it why in an intuitive way but cannot write a full proof of it for the decomposition trying to get a linear system or something) then use Cauchy's theorem and integrate all of these on  different circles with their center at each root  and argue that  the integral is the same as the sum of those circle integrals. Now since $\frac {1}{z-z_n}$ will be analytic inside the circle when I'm integrating on circles that do not contain $z_n$  some  of those integrals  will be zero. and now since my curves are of the form $\gamma(t)=z_n+e^{it}$ , $t \in [0,2\pi]$ the rest of the integrals  will look like $$\int_0^{2\pi}  \frac{Aie^{ti}} {e^{it}}\,{\rm d}t $$  and all of them will be $A_i$.

Is my proof correct? Only part I cannot show is that I won't have any problem with decomposing the fraction. And I'm also using the assumption that after the decomposition I'll have as numerators simple complex numbers not not functions of any kind.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $P(z)=\sum_{k=1}^na_kz^k$ be a polynomial of order $n>1$.  Assume that all of the zeros, $z_k$, $k=1,\dots,n$, are distinct.  Then, we can write $P(z)=a_n\prod_{k=1}^n(z-z_k)$.

Next, using partial fraction expansion, we can write the reciprocal of $P(z)$ as

$$\begin{align}
\frac{1}{P(z)}&=\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{A_k}{z-z_k} \tag 1
\end{align}$$

where $A_k$ are the residues.  Now, multiplying $(1)$ by $a_n\prod_{j=1}^n(z-z_j)$ yields

$$\begin{align}
\frac{a_n\prod_{j=1}^n(z-z_j)}{P(z)}=a_n\sum_{k=1}^n A_k \frac{\prod_{j=1}^n(z-z_j)}{(z-z_k)} \tag 2
\end{align}$$

The left-hand side of $(2)$ is equal to $1$, whereas the right-hand side is a polynomial of order $n-1$.  Therefore, the coefficients of the polynomial on the right-hand side must be zero for all but the zeroth order term.  In particular, the coefficient on the leading term is given by $a_n\sum_{k=1}^n A_k$.  Since, this must be zero, we find that

$$\sum_{k=1}^n A_k=0$$

Inasmuch as $\oint_C \frac{1}{P(z)}\,dz=2\pi i \sum_{k=1}^n A_k $, then

$$\frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint_C \frac{1}{P(z)}\,dz=0$$

as was to be shown!

Comment: where does the integral comes in?

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Thanks!  Much appreciative.

Comment: @ManolisLyviakis $\frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint_C \frac{1}{P(z)}\,dz=\sum \text{Residues}=\sum_k A_k$.

Comment: ohh did not know that.

Comment: Would i be able if i proved that after the decomposition of the fraction  if the $A_k$'s are constant complex numbers then using Cauchy theorem prove that  the  integrals after breaking the original integral into the sum of the decomposition are zeroes (break my curve into the circles around the zeroes of the polynomial).WIthout Using any residue theorem Just that the $A_k$ are constant.Which is my main question.Are the $Ak$'s constant ?when i decompose a fraction such as $\frac{1}{p(z)} $ ?

Comment: Yes, the $A_k$ terms are constant complex numbers, which are independent of $z$.

Comment: nice one, $\,$ (+1)

Comment: @tired Thanks much!!

Comment: @ManolisLyviakis Note that $P(z)=a_n(z-z_1)(z-z_2)\cdots (z-z_n)$.  Then, note $$\lim_{z\to z_k}\frac{z-z_k}{P(z)}=\lim_{z\to z_k}\frac{1}{P'(z)}=\frac{1}{P'(z_k)}=\prod_{j\ne k}^n \frac{1}{z_k-z_j}\ne 0$$exists when the $z_k$ are distinct.

Comment: @ManolisLyviakis I thought that [THIS REFERENCE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_fraction_decomposition#Basic_principles) and [THIS ONE](http://www.math.ubc.ca/~feldman/m121/partdecomp.pdf) would be useful

Comment: Oh thanks that is what i exactly needed

Answer (score 7):

I think you are over-complicating it a bit, it is not necessary to recover the coefficients of the partial fraction decomposition, it is enough to exploit [the residue theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residue_theorem) and the [ML lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Estimation_lemma). If the degree of $P$ is $n\geq 2$ and all its zeroes lies inside $|z|<R$,
$$\forall M\geq R,\qquad \oint_{|z|=R}\frac{dz}{P(z)}=\oint_{|z|=M}\frac{dz}{P(z)} $$
since both integrals equal $2\pi i$ times the sum of the residues of $f(z)=\frac{1}{P(z)}$ at its poles.
 But if $|z|$ is large we have $\left|P(z)\right|\geq C |z|^n $, hence
$$\left|\oint_{|z|=M}\frac{dz}{P(z)}\right|\leq \frac{2\pi M}{CM^n} $$
that goes to zero as $M\to +\infty$, and the only non-trivial part of the claim is proved.

Comment: i know it can be done with residue theorem .Everything can be done with residue theorem.haha joking i just wanted to see if my approach is correct and if the decomposition of fraction on C always gives constants on numerators.!!!!

Comment: @ManolisLyviakis: well, the coefficients of the partial fraction decomposition are given by the residues at the poles, so we are following almost the same path.

Comment: I do not know the residue theorem .Could you explain me what do you mean by saying "residues at the poles" , and that we are following the same path? :)

Comment: @ManolisLyviakis: if $\frac{1}{P(z)}=\frac{A}{z-z_1}+\frac{B}{z-z_2}$, then $$ A = \lim_{z\to z_1}\frac{z-z_1}{P(z)}=\text{Res}\left(\frac{1}{P(z)},z=z_1\right).$$

Comment: With your formulation, assuming $n\geq 2$, the problem boils down to showing that $A+B+C+\ldots = 0$. In my proof, that is granted by the ML lemma.

Comment: Why $A$ equals that limits seems like ti goes to zero!

Comment: @ManolisLyviakis: that is quite trivial if you write it down: $$ \lim_{z\to z_1}\left(\frac{A(z-z_1)}{z-z_1}+\frac{B(z-z_1)}{z-z_2}\right)= A$$

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio what if i want to recover the coefficients and do it the way  i described?

Comment: @ManolisLyviakis: *the way you described* means by solving a linear system? That is just as fine, you'll end with the same set of coefficients, but are you able to prove that the sum of such coefficients is zero with your approach? That is the whole point of the question.

Comment: I can prove that the integrals of the form $\int \frac{c}{z-z_0}$ around a small circle  with center $z_0$ which does not contain the other zeroes   is zero.ANd since i can break my initial integral into the sum of Integrals around those circles. Ill get a Zero since the integrals of the form $\int\frac{c}{z-z_0}$ after paremetrization of the curve $\oint_0^{2π}\frac{cie^it}{e^{nit}}$  are zero.

Comment: those integrals are not even zero my bad .those integras give 2πi *c so ill get a form of $2πι( c_1+c_2+...c_n)$ So ill have to prove they are zero after all my bad i though  the integrals where zero.

Comment: Exactly, the last integral you mentioned equals $2\pi i c$, hence you have to show that the sum of those c constants is zero. Ml is one way, Mark provided another one.

Comment: So according to residues definition these constants are the coefficients of the laurent series of the reciprocal of a polynomial?