# Prove this equality using a complex polynomial lower bound

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration

Using the fact that if
$P(z)=a_nz^n +···+a_1z+a_0,$
is a polynomial of degree $n$ then there is $R_0 > 0$ such that for $|z| > R_0$ the polynomial can be bounded from below as
$$|P(z)|>\frac{1}{2}|a_n||z|^n$$I need to show that if $P(z)$ is polynomial of degree $n ≥ 2$ and $C_R$ is the circle of radius $R$ centered at 0 then
$$\lim_{R\rightarrow \infty} \int_{C_R} \frac{1}{P(z)}dz=0$$

Any hints or help would be appreciated

Comment: You have an upper bound for $\left| \frac{1}{P(z)}\right|$ and you know the length of $C_r$, so .... ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Proof that $\frac {1} {2\pi i} \oint \frac {{\rm d}z} {P(z)} $ over a closed curve is zero.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1897089/proof-that-frac-1-2-pi-i-oint-frac-rm-dz-pz-over-a-closed-cur) – [Jack's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1897107/42969) is what you are looking for.

Comment: But if we have a bound for $|P(z)|$, how can we use it for $|\int \frac{1}{P(z)}dz|$?